# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. with a non null object.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Ok I'm having this problem that is driving me crazy, I'm doing a search for a website, and it works great on my machine but when I upload it to gearhost it just blow with this error :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 43:         @if (Model != null)
>   Line 44:         {
>    Line 45: 
>   if (Model.Any())
>   Line 46:             {

The error appear on Line 45, even though I'm sure I know its not null and its and IEnumerable.

My Model in razor is declared as follow:

```
@model IEnumerable<Posada>
```

And this does work if I send an empty search, but not when I use a string that returns rows or other that does not return any.

In my controller I just return a IEnumerable and use it as the model.

```
 IEnumerable<Posada> posadas = unitOfWork.PosadaRepository.Get(includeProperties: "Estado,Lugar")
                .Where(p => p.Nombre.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(query) ||
                            p.Estado.Nombre.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(query) ||
                            p.Lugar.Nombre.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(query))

                .OrderBy(p => p.Id)
                .Skip((page - 1)*pagingInfo.ItemsPerPage)
                .Take(pagingInfo.ItemsPerPage);
```

Comment: Model won't be null if you just set it to an `IEnumerable`, however, once you call `Any()`, all of your `Where`, `OrderBy`, and other LINQ methods will actually trigger. My thought is something in `p` you are dotting off of is `null`.

Comment: TyCobb you are right.. I knew it was a dumb mistake but really was not able to see it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember `IEnumerable<>` only evaluates the query when it needs to, so as stated by the other answer, when you use `Any()`, your query gets evaluated and in that case either `Estado` or `Lugar` can be null.

Try something like:

```
(p.Estado != null && p.Estado.Nombre.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(query)) ||
(p.Lugar != null && p.Lugar.Nombre.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(query)))
```

Comment: is that called numbre uno which is presented at advertising?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like `NullReferenceException` happens when you enumerate `IEnumerable` (when you execute `Any()`). `IEnumerable` is not null, and then most likely one gets NullReferenceException:

```
p.Nombre.ToLowerInvariant()
p.Estado.Nombre.ToLowerInvariant()
p.Lugar.Nombre.ToLowerInvariant()
pagingInfo.ItemsPerPage
```